# How to translate text automatically using Google Translate API (or any other approach) in python

Tags: python, nlp, machine-translation

I have a dataset of reviews from TripAdvisor and I would like to translate non-English reviews into English.

The reviews are in many different languages: my dataset contains reviews in 44 different languages including English reviews which are around a quarter of the total, followed by Italian, German, Spanish and French reviews which are respectively 14%, 11% 6%, and 5.5% of the reviews.

I detect the different languages using the [`langdetect` package](https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/).

```
from langdetect import detect

language = detect(title)
```

Then I tried to use the package [googletrans](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/) to translate the text.
However, when I tried to perform a small test I get the following error:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()

translator.translate('Buongiorno mi chiamo Alberto')
```

[image]

Does anyone know a way to translate reviews (knowing or not the language ) to English using python
for a dataset of around 10k reviews?

Comment: I have also tried to use the following code from [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_text_processing/python_text_translation.htm) with no success  ```from translate import Translator
translator= Translator(to_lang="German")
translation = translator.translate("Good Morning!")
print translation ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a known error in the package that can be solved by installing `googletrans==4.0.0rc1` as mentioned in [the github issue](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/354). This indeed seems to solves the issue when trying it myself:

```
from googletrans import Translator
translator = Translator()
translator.translate('Buongiorno mi chiamo Alberto').text
# Good morning my name is Alberto
```